# Show that the set is not bounded - formal proof - $D = \{(x,y)\in R^2|y=\frac 1 x\}$

Tags: unbounded-operators

is there any way to prove with epsilon \ other way that the set is unbounded?
$$D=\{(x,y)\in R^2\mid xy=1\} = \{(x,y)\in R^2\mid y=\frac 1  x\}$$
Here is a proof my exerciser at class did ( which is not enough proof for me, If there is way to prove with epsilon, I will be glad if there is ):
let $M\in R$, happens: $(M, \frac 1 M )\in D$
Thus:
$||M + \frac 1 M|| = (M^2 + (\frac 1 M)^2)^{(\frac 1 2)} \ge M$
Thus, not bounded.
Is there any other proof for it?
something with $\epsilon$, any other way which is more friendly?

Comment: What definition of boundedness are you working with?  Does it have anything to do with $\epsilon$?

Comment: Nope. But there is a way to show with epsilon or something similliar no? almost all proofs was with epsilon. but still, even if there is no epsilon, how can I prove it differently than my exerciser? cus I didnt understand his proof

Comment: Is there any other proof with is more "trivial" and understandable?

Comment: $\epsilon$ usually denotes a small positive number, which has nothing to do with boundedness whatsoever.  Again, can you show the definition of boundedness that you are working with?

Comment: Oh one minute, sorry

Comment: $D$ is bounded if there exists $M>0$ such that $D$ is contained in the ball of radius $M$.

Comment: Good.  We are trying to prove that $D$ is *not* bounded.  According to the definition you gave, this is the same as showing that there does *not* exist $M > 0$ such that $D$ is contained in a ball of radius $M$.  By De Morgan's laws for quantifiers, this is the same as showing that, for all $M > 0$, $D$ is *not* contained in a ball of radius $M$.

Comment: @L.F. Yea, the problem is, the prove above my exercises gave, is not related to a ball. I dont know which ball he gave, and just something in general, is there any "common" balls I should think of?

Comment: Your teacher did exactly what was required: he took an arbitrary $M>0$ and proved that $D$ is not contained in "the" ball of radius $M$ (more precisely: the open ball of radius $M$ and center $(0,0)$), by showing some pair which belongs to $D$ and not to that ball. But he certainly did not write $\|M+\frac1M\|,$ which means nothing, instead of $\|(M,\frac1M)\|,$ which is indeed equal to $(M^2 + (\frac 1 M)^2)^{(\frac 1 2)}.$

Comment: I can take which ball I like?
So the norm, is basically $||(x,y) - (x_0,y_0)||$, when x,y is the D part, minus the $x_0, y_0$ of ball? ( which are both equal to 0 ). 
And just a question, how should I think which balls to assign? I am having trouble ( as you just see )

Comment: According to the definition you gave for boundedness, you cannot "take which ball you like": by the reasoning detailed above by L.F. you must show that for *all* $M>0,$ $D$ is not contained in "the" ball of radius $M,$ which, because of your "the" and not "a", tacitely means: the open ball of radius $M$ and center $(0,0).$

Comment: About the norm you just did, sorry, yea, I just noticed it. ,my bad.
Regaridng the solution itself, when he received the expression in sqrt and saw it was bigger then M, why does it prove its not bounded? because all I am saying is for All $M>0$, the set is not in the ball. but I am not saying the set is bounded by M

Comment: About what you wrote, got it, thanks :)
And one last thing regarding what I just wrote is my final question, then I understood completely :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that :
$$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}^*, \left(n, \dfrac{1}{n}\right) \in D$$
and :
$$\left\| \left(n, \dfrac{1}{n}\right) \right\|^2 = n^2 + \dfrac{1}{n^2} \to +\infty$$
then $D$ is unbounded.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I dont have to show that for $M>0$? is it any different from $N$ belong to the natural teams? or it is the same.
and just a question, what does it mean theoretically that the limit goes to infinity? what does it say about the set?

Comment: $x_n \to +\infty$ means that $x_n$ becomes big enough when $n$ is big. Which means that $D$ contains elements with big enough norm so $D$ can't be bounded.

Comment: I see, thank you very much :)

Comment: You're welcome.